# Draytek vigor 2820 force specific traffic via static IP

Tags: networking

I've got a Draytek Vigor 2820 that's used to connect to the internet.  WAN1 is used as an ADSL backup, and WAN2 is our main fibre connection.  WAN2 has a total of 6 IP addresses, a single dynamic one and 5 static IPs and is configured up as a PPPoE connection with DynamicIP.

I use NAT Port Redirection to open up some specific ports to various servers (web development, FTP, RDC etc)
I use NAT Open Ports to open up some static IP ports to specific servers
I use NAT Address Mapping to force all traffic received on one static IP to our Exchange server

What I want to do is to force outgoing traffic to use one of the static IPs and have hit a brick wall.  Ideally I'd like to force specific traffic but would settle for all!

Under LAN is the ability to configure Static Routes, but this is purely there to allow internal routing (for VLANs).

Anybody else who has this type of router and can give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, managed to work this one out.

Under WAN > Internet Access, select WAN2

On the PPPoE page, change the "Fixed IP" to Yes and enter one of the static IP's into the Fixed IP Address box.  Click OK and then reboot the router.

All traffic will now go from that IP address.  If you go back to the same page and click WAN IP Alias, the top spot will have the IP address entered in it which will likely be repeated in the list, I just removed the 'double' from the NAT pool and everything seems to work OK.

Sadly there appears to be no way of having all traffic to one IP being sent via one static IP